# Issue sending mail attachment

Tags: android

I am sending mail through my application mail is sent but the attached text is not sent with it.

```
public class Email extends Activity {
        Button send;
        EditText address, subject, emailtext;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.share);
        send=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmitShare);
        address=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittexttoShare);
        subject=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextsubjectShare);


        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
                            emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");  
                                    //  final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                                      emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

                                      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ address.getText().toString()});

                                      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText());

                               //       emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailtext.getText());

                                    Email.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

                        }
                });
    }
}
```

From this application user can share a link, although mail is sent from it but text is empty

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are doing

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailtext.getText());
```

when you should make a call to toString(), so it's going to be:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailtext.getText().toString());
```